# What is the ATFM Project BOBCAT and why is it important?

Tags: air-traffic-control

Aerothai, the ANSP of Thailand, runs an ATFM Project called [BOBCAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bay_of_Bengal_Cooperative_Air_Traffic_Flow_Management_System) (Bay of Bengal Cooperative Air Traffic Flow Management System).

Why is it so important? And why is an ASNP from Thailand running a project, that spans across most of South Asia?

Comment: @Federico I'm not sure of the relevance of the Meta thread you linked. In particular (related to your answer there), this is not a question from a new user: it's from somebody who's been here for three years. Also, "This question does not show any research effort" is given as a reason for downvoting on the mouse-over text of the downvote button, so is clearly something that's discouraged across the whole network.

Comment: This looks like the sort of question where you can at least find out the basics with Google. Please do so, as people tend to be disinclined to put effort into answering a question whose asker also seems to have put in no effort.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Did I not clarify the question in the meantime? I'd like to know, why this is so important, ANSPs in the region seem to refer to this and I want to know why. When you google the project, you find a little information, but not why this exists and why aerothai does this. I'd also like to clarify, that I don't come here, so that other people google an answer for me; I come here knowing, that this is an aviation community, so I thought, people involved or people in the know would be able to answer.

Comment: No, you clarified it nearly half an hour after my most recent comment.

Comment: @mins Important to other ANSPs in the region

Comment: Not sure Aerothai is an ANSP, seems more like Arinc. See [also](https://www.icao.int/APAC/Meetings/2011_bbacg21/WP13%20Attachment%20BOBCAT%20Operational%20Updates%20and%20Future%20Enhancements.pdf). BOBCAT seems to be the equivalent of [CFMU](https://www.skybrary.aero/index.php/Central_Flow_Management_Unit_(CFMU)) (now NMOC).